# Are All Members of House Targaryen Impervious to Flames?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* we see that Daenarys can't be burned by flames, would this ability have extended to the rest of the members of House Targaryen?

The reason I ask is that, during the episode where the Night's Watch has a funeral for Aemon, we see that they have him resting on a funeral pyre which they then set alight. The custom would make perfect sense for anyone else, but seeing as he's a member of House Targaryen, it seems like this would have been a fruitless endeavour because it wouldn't actually burn him.

Maybe they'd only have this ability whilst alive though? Is there any mention of this being a trait for Targaryens anywhere in the books? I'm only nearing the end of the first book in the series but I've been keeping up with the show.

Comment: Well, Daenerys' brother certainly didn't react well to it either. I guess it's more of a "true dragon-whatever chosen one" thing than something inherent to the entire Targaryen family.

Comment: Wasn't her brother more....melted than burned though? He had a pot of molten gold poured over his head.

Comment: Hmm, could be. But I actually think we had that question before, or a largely similar one. I'll go look for it.

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13165/49.

Comment: I don't however know if it's really a duplicate. The answers all seem to adress your question, even if the question isn't really the same.

Comment: Hmm although it raises the question of in Season 2 when she's being chained in the room with her dragons by the warlock, they breathe the fire right past her to burn him and she's unaffected by it, so maybe in the show's canon she does have an immunity to flame?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I also thought.

Comment: [GRRM says no](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/37473/3267)

Comment: Also, cremation seems to be the standard funerary practice favored by the Targaryens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copied from my answer on SF&F SE...

The Targeryens, are not immune to fire as stated multiple times by George RR Martin.

Via [westeros.org](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/945/)

> some fans are reading too much into the scene in GAME OF THRONES where the dragons are born -- which is to say, it was never the case that all Targaryens are immune to all fire at all times.

[From a chat...](http://web.archive.org/web/20001005212114/eventhorizon.com/sfzine/chats/transcripts/031899.html)

> Granny, thanks for asking that. It gives me a chance to clear up a common misconception. TARGARYENS ARE NOT IMMUNE TO FIRE! The birth of Dany's dragons was unique, magical, wonderous, a miracle. She is called The Unburnt because she walked into the flames and lived. But her brother sure as hell wasn't immune to that molten gold.

In response to the followup question asking if Dany would survive the fire again.

> Probably not.

Specifically answering your question about funerals, the Targaryens always burned their dead. So even if there were some partial fire immunity, it wouldn't last when the person was dead.

From [A Feast For Crows (Sam POV Chapter):](http://towerofthehand.com/books/104/036/index.html)

> He will still burn , Sam thought miserably, only now I have to do it. **The Targaryens always gave their fallen to the flames.** Quhuru Mo would not allow a funeral pyre aboard the Cinnamon Wind, so Aemon’s corpse had been stuffed inside a cask of blackbelly rum to preserve it until the ship reached Oldtown.

Note: In the books Aemon leaves for Oldtown with Sam and dies along the way.  However I think that passage should still be relevant for the TV show.

Comment: Please add the actual links to the sources you've cited.

Comment: @Mooz done. Best I could do on the book passage was a link to the chapter summary