# Is Daenerys immune to fire 'always'?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones*, Daenerys has managed to survive fire or extreme heat in several instances:

1. When Daenerys' dragons were born in the season 1 finale, "Fire and Blood" (*Game of Thrones*, S01E10)
2. Killing the khals by locking them inside the temple of Vaes Dothrak and lighting the place on fire in "Book of the Stranger" (*Game of Thrones*, S06E04) - while all the men burned alive, Daenerys emerged from the hut unscratched.
3. The steaming hot bath in "Winter is Coming" (*Game of Thrones*, S01E01) - Daenerys is warned by a servant that "it's too hot, my lady", but she steps in without flinching
4. Daenerys casually picks up the dragon eggs that were roasting on hot coals, in "A Golden Crown" (*Game of Thrones*, S01E06) - when the Dothraki handmaiden, Irri, rushes in and knocks them off her hands, Daenery's hands are unscathed, while Irri's now have burn marks

Here she didn't show immunity to heat, but made a relevant remark:

- Her comment, "He was no dragon. Fire cannot kill a dragon", at the
  time of Viserys' death in "A Golden Crown" (*Game of Thrones*,
  S01E06)

George R. R. Martin, author of the novel series that the show is adapting, has stated that the Targaryens are not immune to fire (at least in the books).

Were the above instances in which she is shown to be immune to fire (in the show) unique, or has she had this ability her whole life? If so, when and how did Daenerys acquire this ability?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9356/is-daenerys-targaryen-immune-to-fire

Comment: Obviously GRRM and D&D have diverged on this point.... Show-verse Dany seems to be fireproof.

Comment: I feel like this is a dupe

Comment: I took the liberty of editing this post to make the question a bit more clear, if you I went to far please roll it back.

Comment: Don't forget the 3. Hot bath, 4. Burning hot dragon eggs, 5. Her comment about true Targaryens and fire

Comment: Related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35418/are-all-members-of-house-targaryen-impervious-to-flames?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank u for the edit and suggestions.i have edited and included your suggestions

Comment: Only for fires where Dothraki men are a fuel source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the show, despite what GRRM said, Daenerys appears to be fireproof. She kills the Khals long after her dragons are born and planned the murders around her ability to survive fire. Furthermore, we have Daenerys' words upon watching her brother die -

> He was no dragon. Fire cannot kill a dragon.

It seems at this point in the show that they have decided to impart permanent fire immunity on Daenerys.

Edit: Since answering the question has changed. Considering we see Daenerys take the hot bath in the very first episode, it seems she has had fire immunity her whole life, but we do not know. Nothing in the show tells us how or when she came to be immune to fire.

Comment: You are merely repeating back the points that OP has already made in his question, and then attaching a conclusion that isn't backed by any official source - OP has already made the point that the evidence presented in the show lends good credence that she is permanently immune, he is asking for concrete confirmation.

Comment: @GhotiandChips The post was heavily edited. When I answered it simply asked how she was able to survive burning the Khals if she isn't immune to fire, as GRRM said. He added everything to the question that has been supplied in the answers. At this point, the question is simply asking something we don't know.

Comment: I suppose that's fair, though I suppose the spirit of the question, regardless of additional in-show references added in through edits, is looking for an official, undebatable point, either raised in the show or out of it (through behind-the-scenes, Inside the Episode, interviews, etc.) that confirms her immunity. The points you raise in your answer, despite being there before the question was edited to include your points and more, don't really do much except reinforce that the show is strongly implying immunity, but there is no hardline, definitive confirmation. Not bashing your answer -

Comment: -cont'd- I understand now that it *was* more relevant when you answered it, so I give you the benefit of the doubt, I remove my downvote, even if I still feel it isn't answering or providing the information that the question is looking for. No hard feelings and apologies for the initial confusion on my part.

Comment: It's interesting that they decided to keep her fire proof, but not to provide her with fire proof underwear or clothing.

Answer (score 5):

### It's a one-time magical thing in the source novels.

From an [**interview with GRRM**](https://www.dakkadakka.com/dakkaforum/posts/list/449541.page?userfilterid=33891)...

> Granny: Do Targaryens become immune to fire once they "bond" to their dragons?
>
> George_RR_Martin: Granny, thanks for asking that. It gives me a chance to clear up a common misconception. TARGARYENS ARE NOT IMMUNE TO FIRE! **The birth of Dany's dragons was unique, magical, wondrous, a miracle. She is called The Unburnt because she walked into the flames and lived.** But her brother sure as hell wasn't immune to that molten gold.
>
> Revanshe: So she won't be able to do it again?
>
> George_RR_Martin: Probably not.
>
> <sup>[From a Q&A on SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133135/could-wildfire-burn-daenerys-targaryen)</sup>

---

### In the show it's less clear

The show has diverged somewhat from this "one-time" thing in that there have been other occasions where Danaerys has seemed immune to fire. However, we don't know how permanent this *ability* actually is...so the answer is...

**"We don't know."**

Comment: About the show, it seems that Dany has always been immune, even before the birth of her dragons. At least, it's _hinted_ at, when she takes a bath in Illyrio's mansion. The chamber maid warns her that the water is way too hot, and it seems that way (steam coming off it), yet Dany seems unphased and distracted by something different, so I infer from that that she wasn't in pain.